# Top forms on product manifolds come from top forms on factors

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $M^n$ and $N^m$ be oriented manifolds and give $M\times N$ the product orientation. Let $\pi_1:M\times N\to M$ and $\pi_2:M\times N\to N$ be the projections onto each factor. I am asked to show that every compactly supported $(n+m)$-form $\chi$ is of the form $\chi=h\,\pi_1^*\omega\wedge\pi_2^*\eta,$ where $h:M\times N\to\mathbb R$ is smooth, and $\omega,\eta$ are top forms on $M$ and $N$ respectively.

This seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm stuck in a rut. I want to just do it locally and paste the answers together, but it's not working. I cover the support of $\chi$ by charts $U\times V$ on which $\chi=h_{U,V}\,d\bar x_U^1\wedge\cdots\wedge d\bar x_U^n\wedge d\bar y_V^1\wedge\cdots \wedge d\bar y_V^m$ (here if $(U,x)$ and $(V,y)$ are charts on $M,N$ respectively, then $(U\times V,\bar x\times \bar y)$ denotes the induced chart on the product). I then take partitions of unity $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ on $M$ and $N$ respectively, which are both subordinate to this cover, and write $$\chi=\sum_{U,V}\phi_U\cdot\psi_V\cdot h_{U,V}\,d\bar x_U^1\wedge\cdots\wedge d\bar x_U^n\wedge d\bar y_V^1\wedge\cdots \wedge d\bar y_V^m.$$ However, I can't break this sum up in a way that will get $\chi$ into the form I want. Any suggestions for how to save this solution, or should I try some other method of attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is that you can actually work globally instead of locally; all the local-to-global work can be done just on $M$ and $N$ themselves using their orientability.  So, just let $\omega$ and $\eta$ be any nowhere vanishing top forms on $M$ and $N$ (these exist since $M$ and $N$ are orientable), so $\pi_1^*\omega\wedge \pi_2^*\eta$ is a nowhere vanishing top form on $M\times N$.  Any other top form is then a scalar multiple of $\pi_1^*\omega\wedge \pi_2^*\eta$ at each point, and thus can be written in the form $h\pi_1^*\omega\wedge \pi_2^*\eta$ for some smooth function $h$.

(If you want $\omega$ and $\eta$ to be compactly supported as well, then you can choose them to have large enough supports so that $\pi_1^*\omega\wedge \pi_2^*\eta$ is still nonzero on the entire support of $\chi$.)

Comment: This answer is perfect. Very simple. Can you remind me why $h$ is forced to be smooth here? I guess it's just true that for a fixed top form $\omega$ every other top form can be written as $f\omega$ for some smooth $f,$ but I don't see exactly why.

Comment: Just look in local coordinates; both top forms can be written as some smooth functions times $dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, so you can just divide those smooth functions to get $h$ (and you aren't dividing by $0$ since the one you're dividing by is nonvanishing).

Comment: Great. Thanks a ton. You've been a great help.